# Prove that the number of solutions to $x^a = 1 \pmod p$ in $\mathbb Z_p^\times$ is $\gcd(a,p-1)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number and $a\geq 1$ an integer.  Show that the number of solutions to $x^a = 1 \pmod p$ in $\mathbb  Z_p^\times$ is $\gcd(a,p-1)$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** Let $b$ be a primitive root mod $p$. Then $x=b^i$ for some $0 \leq i \leq p-2$.

Now, $x^a \equiv 1 \pmod p \Leftrightarrow (p-1)|ai \,.$

Comment: Could you explain with more details your way? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Applying [Discrete Logarithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiscreteLogarithm.html) wrt an arbitrary primitive root $g\pmod p,$

$$a\cdot ind_gx\equiv0\pmod {p-1}$$

Now using [Linear Congruence](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Solution_of_Linear_Congruence) Theorem, as $(a,p-1)$ divides $0,$ the congruence will have exactly $(a,p-1)$ solutions.

This can be generalized to any number $n$ having at least one primitive root where $p-1$ will be replaced with $\phi(n)$